# Ajuda com join em consulta lambda

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda

Tenho as classes:

```
profissional
{
    int id;
    int idUnidade;
    string nome;
}

unidade
{
    int id;
    string nome;
}

profissionalUnidade
{
    string profissionalNome;
    string unidadeNome;
}
```

Estou fazendo uma consulta assim:

```
listaProfissionalUnidade = (from p in profissionais
join u in unidades on p.idUnidade = u.id
select new profissionalUnidade()
{
    profissionalNome = p.nome,
    unidadeNome = u.nome
}).ToList();
```

Assim, ele me lista todos os profissionais que tem algum vínculo com uma unidade. Porém, eu também preciso que seja retornado pra mim, os profissionais que não tem vínculos.

Como devo fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o `left join`, isso ficaria assim.

```
listaProfissionalUnidade = (from p in profissionais
join u in unidades on p.idUnidade = u.id into u1
from u2 in u1.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new profissionalUnidade()
{
    profissionalNome = p.nome,
    unidadeNome = u2 == null ? "" : u2.nome
}).ToList();
```

Ou seja, o linq jogar o resultado do seu u em u1 e caso não encontre um valor correspondente na outra tabela ele criar um objeto null usando o `DefaultIfEmpty`.

Conforme comentado abaixo, você praticamente só precisar fazer a repetição do trecho abaixo.

```
join u in unidades on p.idUnidade = u.id into u1
from u2 in u1.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

ou seja;

```
join u in unidades on p.idUnidade = u.id into u1
from u2 in u1.DefaultIfEmpty()
join l in unidades on u.idOutraUnidade = l.id into l1
from l2 in l1.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: o código funcionou de boa com duas tabelas, tem como você postar um exemplo com três ou mais tabelas?

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo, postado.